# Page not found at polls/1/details in Django-2.1

Tags: python, django

[image]

I'm trying to get the Choice details but the page isn't rendering. Here is link to project: https://github.com/tsuryaa/my_project

Comment: Hi, Surya. Welcome to SO. Please don't post screenshots of code, post actual code and please spend some time on formatting. The formatting help is available in the editing window, and you can read more about how to ask questions on the  [HOw to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: For a Django project we will need to see your models, your url conf and the views that serve that page.

Comment: Also, I couldn't find your details.html anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

your url pattern and href link is wrong;

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', index, name='polls_list'),
  path('<int:id>/details/', views.details, name='poll_details'),
  path('<int:id>/', views.poll, name='single_poll')
]
```

and change polls details url;

```
    <li> <a href="{% url 'poll_details' id=question.id %}">{{question.title}} </a></li>
```

change therewith and try again.

Comment: Please look at [this](https://github.com/tsuryaa/my_project/blob/master/ems/poll/views.py#L13) function first.

Comment: Are you change ```path('<int:id>/details/', views.details, name='poll_details'),```? and change details function;
```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
# add this in views.py
def details(request, id):
    try:
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=id) # or id=id
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: {}".format(e))

    return render(request, 'polls/details.html', {'context': question})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in your details view under poll app.

```
try:
    question=Question.objects.all.get(id=id)
except:
    raise Http404
```

You don't have a valid query and you are raising 404 in except statements that results in showing you 404 page not found.

Here is the fixed code:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
def details(request,id=None):
    context={}
    try:
        question=Question.objects.get(id=id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        question = "Sorry! Poll does not exits with this id"
    context['question']=question
    return render(request, 'polls/details.html', context)
```